# Python Beautiful Soup Scraping Exact Content From Charts

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

In python using beautiful soup I want to be able to grab specific text `<a>/numbers<td>` from a sortable table online.

http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?archive=false&conference=null&role=OPP&offensiveStatisticCategory=null&defensiveStatisticCategory=INTERCEPTIONS&season=2014&seasonType=REG&tabSeq=2&qualified=false&Submit=Go

I have attempted this about a million times and can't figure it out.

This is the best I could do:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import requests
import pymongo
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?archive=false&conference=null&role=OPP&offensiveStatisticCategory=null&defensiveStatisticCategory=INTERCEPTIONS&season=2014&seasonType=REG&tabSeq=2&qualified=false&Submit=Go').read())

find = soup('a', text="Miami Dolphins")

print find
```

I don't know how to find/call the 10th (9th in python) < td > tag after Miami Dolphins.

The table code looks something like this:

```
<table id="result" style="width:100%" cellpadding="0" class"data-table1"
cellspacing="0">
   <caption class="thd1">...</caption>
   <tbody>...</tbody>
   <tbody>
      <tr class="odd">...</tr>
      <tr class="even">...</tr>
      <tr class="odd">...</tr>
      <tr class="even">...</tr>
      <tr class="odd">...</tr>
      <tr class="even">...</tr>
      <tr class="odd">...</tr>
      <tr class="even">...</tr>
      <tr class="odd">...</tr>
      <tr class="even">...</tr>
      <tr class="odd">...</tr>
      <tr class="even">...</tr>
      <tr class="odd">...</tr>
      <tr class="even">...</tr>
      <tr class="odd">...</tr>
      <tr class="even">
         <td>14</td>
         <td>
            <a href="/teams/miamidolphins/profile?team=MIA onclick=
            "s_objectID="http://www.nfl.com/teams.miamidolphins/profile?
            team=MIA_1";return this.s_oc?this.s_oc(e):true">Miami Dolphins</a>    *********I want to grab team name**********
         </td>
         <td>

         16

         </td>
         <td>24.2</td>
         <td>

         388

         </td>
         <td class="right">...</td>
         <td class="right">...</td>
         <td class="right">...</td>
         <td class="right">...</td>
         <td class="right">...</td>
         <td class="right">...</td>
         <td class="sorted right">...</td>
           "


           14  ****I want to grab 10th number/<td> tag after team name****


                                        "
         </td>
         <td class="right">...</td>
         <td class="right">...</td>
         <td class="right">...</td>
         <td class="right">...</td
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
import urllib2
from lxml import etree

url = 'http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?archive=false&conference=null&role=OPP&offensiveStatisticCategory=null&defensiveStatisticCategory=INTERCEPTIONS&season=2014&seasonType=REG&tabSeq=2&qualified=false&Submit=Go'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
htmlparser = etree.HTMLParser()

tree = etree.parse(response,htmlparser)

text = tree.xpath('//a[contains(text(),"Miami Dolphins")]/parent::td/following-sibling::td[10]/text()')
if text:
    print text[0].strip()
```

Comment: WOW. I wish I had your skillz!! You're amazing!! Thank you!!

Comment: I don't want to be a pain... Any chance you can explain each line of code so i can understand what is going on? Obviously thanks so much for your help.

Comment: What if i want to use a < td > tag as an anchor point rather than an < a > tag? When I change it, it doesnt seem to work. Also what if I want to want to use a tag from a different < table > (on the same URL) as an anchor point?  A good example would be a player page with multiple tables (Passsing table, Rushing table, and Recieving table... http://www.nfl.com/player/ryantannehill/2532956/careerstats

Comment: do you need the explanation for the answer submitted or need the solution for last comment

Comment: Mainly a solution for my last comment.  The solution to my first post works perfect. Now I'm trying to do the same thing on player pages but having trouble... I tried changing //a.."team name" to //td..."2014" on the player career stats (link in my last comment) and I could not get it to work. I also want to skip to another table on the same page but I do not know how to do that (Passing, Rushing, Revieving) (explained in my last comment).

Comment: may be u should try by urself now and if u are not able to do that then post ur code in stackoverflow or learn xpath and then we can help u...